# Flex items overflowing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a form with first row a single text field 100% width and 2nd row 3 fields equidistant. It works fine on Chrome. However it's overflowing on FireFox.

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form .number {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form .expiry {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="number">
    <input data-stripe="number" placeholder="Credit Card Number" class="" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="expiry">
    <input data-stripe="exp-month" placeholder="MM" class="" type="text">
    <input data-stripe="exp-year" placeholder="YY" class="" type="text">
    <input data-stripe="cvc" placeholder="CVC" class="" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xhr031yr/2/

Comment: There are two problem areas here: (1) Why do the `input` elements shrink in Chrome but not Firefox? and (2) Why do flex items in some cases not shrink by default? See the duplicates for the explanations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will need to set:

```
.form .expiry input {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhr031yr/6/)**

The reason is flex items have `min-width:auto` set by default, and for a replaced element such as `<input>`, it has intrinsic dimensions. The flex item won't shrink when the total width of the input boxes exceeded.

You can also give the `size` attribute a smaller value (default is 20 for text input) to make it smaller:

```
<input type="text" size="3">
```

**References**

- [Automatic Minimum Size of Flex Items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)
- [Replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)
- [HTML `<input>` attribute `size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-size)

Comment: I have a situation where only setting the size to an arbitrary value fixed the problem. In which situations the min-width may not work?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why that's happening, my guess is the way the browser handles the `input` element.

You can achieve the layout by...

1. Add the `box-sizing` rule.
2. Wrapping the `inputs` in a container

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/xhr031yr/5/)

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form .number {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form .expiry {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="number">
    <input data-stripe="number" placeholder="Credit Card Number" class="" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="expiry">
    <div class="input">
      <input data-stripe="exp-month" placeholder="MM" class="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input data-stripe="exp-year" placeholder="YY" class="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input data-stripe="cvc" placeholder="CVC" class="" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!---->
```