# Flex container with input width 100% FF bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, input, flexbox

I have this code:

```html
<body style="width:200px">
  <div style="display: flex">
    <div style="display: flex">
      <div style="width: 40px;height: 10px;background: red"></div>
      <input style="width: 100%" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input style="width: 100%" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you open this code with Chrome and FF you will see a different behavior.
Here is the [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/i8ddCVyMYaiN5R2y?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)

In Chrome (and IE) it will look like this:[image]
And in FF like this:[image]

**My questions:**
1) Why the browsers act differently?
2) I think Chrome is the correct behavior, how can I minimally change my code so FF will be like Chrome? (I still need the display:flex and width 100% on the inputs, also all must be under width: 200px)

Comment: Is it this problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326796/5300921  (min-widht:auto => min-width:0)

Comment: @Rustyjim  Great thanks!